# Python CA Rally API Pyral - User Stories not being found in child projects

Tags: python, python-2.7, rally, pyral

When trying to query User Stories, after updating to pyral version 1.4.1, it no longer find user stories in child projects.

```
entity = "UserStory"
query = '(FormattedID = "US3375")'   
rally.get(entity, query=query)
```

That userstory is found in a project 2 children deep. 
MainProject -> ChildProject -> GrandChildProject -> the above user story.

At version 1.4.1 (current version):

```
200 QueryResult TotalResultCount: 0  Results: []
```

At version 1.1.1 (old version):

```
<pyral.entity.HierarchicalRequirement object at 0x7f2c3c0e3890>
```

Does the API still support finding user stories from child projects? If so, how do you enable it?

Answer (score 3):

Found that adding `projectScopeDown=True` to the get function it works as before.
`entity = "UserStory"
query = '(FormattedID = "US3375")'

rally.get(entity, query=query, projectScopeDown=True)`